# How to list network shares and users in Windows?

Tags: windows

With "net share" I can get a list of shares I'm connected to but how can I get a listing that shows the user info used to connect to a share, if the user is not the same as the logged in user in Windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does going to computermanagement > System Tools > Shared Folders give you what you want?

Answer (score 4):

**[SoftPerfect Network Scanner](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/)** is a free multi-threaded IP, NetBIOS and SNMP scanner with a modern interface and several advanced features. It is intended for both system administrators and general users interested in computer security.

- Pings computers.
- Does not require administrative privileges.
- Detects hardware (MAC) addresses even across routers.
- **Detects hidden shared folders (normally invisible on the network) and write accessible shares.**
- Detects your internal and external IP addresses.
- Scans for listening TCP ports and SNMP services.
- **Retrieves currently logged-on users.**
- You can mount and explore network resources.
- Can launch external third party applications.
- Exports results to HTML, XML, CSV and TXT
- Supports Wake-On-LAN, remote shutdown and sending network messages.
- Retrieves potentially any information via WMI.
- Retrieves information from remote registry.
- It is absolutely free, requires no installation, and does not contain any adware/spyware/malware.

Comment: Thank you Molly, this looks really great, will check ASAP.